# Android Action_DIAL error "No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL"

Tags: java, android-studio

al realizar una llamada usando `Action_DIAL` me salta el siguiente error:

```
09-28 16:47:31.610 2079-2079/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                  Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@a893eb70 }
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:708)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
                                                     at com.example.eac1.EAC1.Trucar(EAC1.java:154)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

La parte del programa es esta:

```
public void Trucar(View vista) {
        // primero pasamos el texto a String para poder analizarlo.
        String textoTelf = telf.getText().toString();
        if (textoTelf == "Valor no definit" || textoTelf.equalsIgnoreCase("Valor no definit") || textoTelf.isEmpty()) { // Si el texto esta vacío..
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El camp ''Telefon'' està buït!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show(); // en aquest cas mostrare sempre que hi estigui el valor no definit i empty podría fer apart
            // verificacions per veure si conté 9 números etc.. Si hem dona temps pulire aquestes coses.

       } else { // Funcion llamar.

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(telf)));
            startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
```

Básicamente quiero que llame a telf pero no me sale! :( No sé que hago mal.. La idea es que el texto lo coje de un EditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error generado que muestra tu `LogCat` es:

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity
>   found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL }

Este error se debe a que el valor del teléfono es incorrecto, string vació o valor null, por esta razón no reconoce el tipo de `Intent`.

**Es importante asegurar que ademas de tener un numero telefónico correcto, este tenga al inicio el esquema para identificar que es una llamada**, en caso debes agregar al inicio del teléfono:

```
tel:+
```

por ejemplo un numero (214)3371154 se tendría que enviar de esta forma:

```
tel:+2143371154
```

Con esto funcionará correctamente tu código:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.valueOf("tel:+2143371154")));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: el problema es que el teléfono me viene de un EditText.. no puedo poner yo uno al azar..

Comment: así que imagino que tengo que analizar que son números?

Comment: @MontseMkd para que sepas que son números, sólo necesitas intentar convertir el valor del editbox a int, si se puede, son puros números, y puedes proceder a hacer el dial :)

Comment: @MontseMkd puedes validar como dice L.Ronquillo si es numerico y le agregas tel:+ al inicio! :)

Comment: ya lo tengo!! GRACIAS!! <3